# Call app template in a different app's template

Tags: python, django

I have a `form.py` that is rendered in a html file called `contactApp/templates/contact/contact.html`. In the template `coreApp/templates/core/core.html` I want to show the first HTML content.

I couldn't find any reasonable answer on Google and here.

Think this might be done using `include` tag but didn't work at all.

In my core html file I put `{% include "contact/contact.html" %}` but seems it is not like that.

Would appreciate if someone help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, show us your views, please

Comment: Can you paste your TEMPLATE_DIRS setting from settings.py?

Comment: Templates don't render forms. Views render templates, and may include forms. You don't give enough information to solve the problem, but thinking of the view as the most important part may help you get to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `extends` template keyword,

**contact/contact.html**:

```
{% block 'title' %}
{{ contact.title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block 'content' %}
{% endblock %}
```

`core/core.html` template can then extend `contact/contact.html`:

**core/core.html:**

```
{% extends "contact/contact.html" %}

{% block 'title' %}
Actually core/core.html!
{% endblock %}

{block 'content' %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

For reference [How do include a dynamic template from another app in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114622/how-do-include-a-dynamic-template-from-another-app-in-django#answer-1114632)

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!